# Updating Django form based on input

Tags: ajax, django, forms

I want to append more fields based on a users selection of `Type of Event`.

What is the best way to add additional fields based on the users selection without refreshing the page?

I was thinking ajax call when user clicks `Add the details` and return html?

Is there a way to do this using the template system with a series of if/else conditionals?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind here...

1)

Attach a jQuery change handler to the 'Type of Event' select element, and execute an ajax request to return the dynamic fields that will need to be displayed.

```
$('#TYPE_OF_EVENT_ID').change(function() {
    $.get('/api/to/return/dynamic/fields/', {'type_of_event': $(this).val()}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        # Update DOM with dynamic content return by data (should probably be JSON)
    });
});
```

2)

Hard code the logic straight into your javascript to handle the case statements to display the dynamic fields depending upon the value which is selected in the 'Type of Event' select element.

```
$('#TYPE_OF_EVENT_ID').change(function() {
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'Special Event':
            # Show Special Event Fields
        case 'Non Special Event':
            # Show Non Special Event Fields
    }
});
```

I'd recommend option 1 as it scales better keeping this logic on the server to be database driven.

Comment: Interesting, I actually thought option 1 was a bit overkill to have server side requests just to update a form, but I'll take your advice